# Why is "piano cucina" a masculine noun?

Tags: word-usage, gender

I have read the following sentence:

> Il succo di frutta è sul piano cucina.
>
> Il frigorifero è accanto al piano cucina.

Why is the `cucina` treated as a masculine noun here? If `cucina` is feminine, it should be transformed into `la piana cucina`, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In *piano cucina* the main noun is *piano* (meaning “surface”, “top”), while *cucina* (“kitchen”) is a kind of attribute.

A more traditional form might be *piano da cucina* or something like that, but in Italian it is not infrequent to find phrases of the form noun+noun, written together or apart. Consider *pescespada* (“swordfish”), *scuola guida* (“driving school”), *busta paga* (“pay packet”), *carrozza ristorante* (“dining car”), *treno merci* (“goods train”) and lots of other ones.

In all these cases the second noun modifies, makes more specific the first one, which is the one to be considered for the gender and number of the whole expression.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious: Is there any noun that unions more than 2 words together? Do the gender and number match the first noun in that case (if possible)?

Comment: @Gardecolo  I never heard any composed word of more than two words. The gender and number match the "head" noun (there's probably a better term for this). It's ***il** pescespada/treno merci* and ***la** scuola guida/busta paga/carrozza ristorante* and *i pesc**i**spad**a*** not *i pescespade* nor *i pescispade*.  Sometimes the "head" noun is **not** the first one, for example in *il capogiro* the head is *giro* not *capo* so we say *i capogiri* and not *i capigiro* nor *i capigiri*.  However sometimes both noun change in the plural... there's no simple rule for all composed words.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thank you for the excellent follow-up.

Comment: @Gardecolo Would something like *servizio assistenza clienti* qualify?

Comment: @Gardecolo: Out of the top of my mind I can't think of 3- (or more) part nouns either, but they are conceivable and would be easily understood: one could create such a werecreature as a *uomo-pescecane* (“swordfishman”), for instance.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I'd see your example more as a full-fledged phrase shortened by omitting articles and prepositions, than as a composite noun. There exist monsters as “scadenza versamento rata pulizia scale condominio".