# "Dipartimento produzione" vs "dipartimento di produzione"

Tags: difference, prepositions

Is there any difference in meaning between "dipartimento produzione" and "dipartimento di produzione" ? Which one is the most usual?

Is "dipartimento produzione" a compound noun or is "produzione" an adjective in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dipartimento produzione* is no compound noun, nor any other standard linguistic construct. It's just a debatable, albeit frequent, Newspeak phrase, slightly calqued from English (up to an inversion), for *dipartimento di produzione*.

Comment: Uhm, a me pare invece che sia una combinazione polirematica nome+nome (vedi la sezione 3.1 [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-polirematiche_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)), esattamente come "treno merci" o "punto vendita", quindi una costruzione abbastanza standard.

Comment: Thanks, @FedericoPoloni. We already had a [variant of this discussion](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5678/why-is-piano-cucina-a-masculine-noun/5679#5679) some four years ago. In my opinion there are two distinct types of juxtapositions of nouns in Italian: legitimate polyrematic phrases such as your _treno merci_ etc., and recent asyndetic constructions (in a comment there I mentioned “scadenza versamento rata pulizia scale condominio").